# MVC3 application and keeping track of what page the user initially entered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, cookies, authentication, registration

and thanks for taking the time to read my question.  We will have visitors to the site that might arrive at another user's profile page.  We will then encourage them to login to the site, or register as new if they are not currently members.  These actions move them pretty far away from that initial page/URL they stated on, but we want to be able to "jump them" back to that page after completing login/sign-up by "keeping track" where they began.  (NOTE: we're using the standard Microsoft membership provider classes, if it matters.)  The "jumping back" part seems straightforward, it is the "keeping track" part that is the problem.

An illustration/example:

A visitor arrives at the site after clicking: www.mysite.com/profiles/ID=108

The visitor then leaves that page to login.  How can we best capture the ID=108 somehow, so that there is a good option for the (logged-in) user to return to that profile page?  I understand from reading that cookies are not optimal, but some of the other options seem to throw a monkey wrench into my thinking since the user is not yet logged-in, etc.

Any concrete steps that I can take to address this in the best MVC3 way?

EDIT:

```
    public ViewResult MyProfile(int? id)
    { 
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MySiteCookie");
    cookie.Value = id.ToString();
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1); //or whatever time is appropriate
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //do some other stuff
    }
```

At the other end, to make use of the cookie, I've put it into the menu (temporarily) in such a way:

```
    var MyProfileId = "";
    if (Request.Cookies["MySiteCookie"] != null)
    {HttpCookie cookie = request.Cookies["MySiteCookie"];
    MyProfileId = Server.HtmlEncode(cookie.Value);}
```

and then you put it into your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand from reading that cookies are not optimal

IMHO cookies are the best way to approach this. When an anonymous user lands on the profiles page simply emit a cookie containing the `id` of the profile that he is currently viewing. Then later when he successfully logs in read this cookie value to obtain the `id` and construct the redirect link and redirect him to this link.

Another possibility is to use server side session but I am mentioning this just as an alternative to cookies and not at all as something that I would recommend.

Comment: Hi Darin, thank you for your answer.  I will investigate cookies again (still going through the learning curve on MVC3) and see what I might have missed/misunderstood.  Nothing on stackoverflow seems to point the way to the best resource for understanding them -- do you happen to know of any online resources for getting cookies emitted/read correctly?

Comment: @edward_h, to read cookies you use `Request.Cookies` and to emit cookies you use `Response.Cookies`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Awesome.  I'm gonna experiment and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

1)  You can use Session in your Controller to store the value:

```
Session.Remove("ID");
Session.Add("ID", "108")
```

And retrieve in the called Controller.

```
ID = Session["ID"];
```

2)  You can pass the ID=108 on the query string from the Login Controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Profile", new { ID = "108" });
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply.  I am a little worried about the querystring idea, since the user could potentially go completely through the entire registration process before arriving back at the page.  (That's multiple pages to pass this through, and 99% of the time we wouldn't have the need for that during new user registration.)  Also, if Darin is right and cookies are possibly also a good choice, how do you feel about them vs. session vars?

Comment: @Edward....I prefer Session because it's on the server.  It is possible (although unlikely) for users to disable cookies on their machine

Comment: Hmm.  We are anticipating a lot of users via mobile web (smartphone), which introduces issues of cookies on different mobile browsers/platforms, but probably makes the chances of people disabling all cookies even more remote.  I will test how well this seems to work, and then post again; if we need to change, I'll attempt your suggestion.  Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the redirection to the login action adding a Url to a query string param.

Let say:  `www.mysite.com/login?ReturnUrl='www.mysite.com/profiles/ID=108'`

I think that this is the default membership provider behaviour, but you can get the ReferrerUrl to place it in the query string on your own.

Comment: Hi Romias, thanks for the reply.  I do think that the membership provider does that, but not if you instead go to through the process for new user registration (see my comment to Mike above.)